# How to implement facebook authorization to allow facebook post hrough android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am having a slight issue with implementing facebook post on android. I am trying to implement it in such a way that when I click a button it automatically posts onto a users wall. Firstly, I don't know where to save the users login information or will the facebook api already handle that? Most importantly, I have tried some sample code and I am having an issue with authorizing the facebookClient.

```
private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener (){

    @Override
    // on click load the asynctask to run.

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        facebookClient = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        facebookAsync = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebookClient);

        if (facebookClient.isSessionValid()) {
            uploadVideoFile();
        }
        else {
            facebookClient.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    (RESULT_CANCELED);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                 (RESULT_CANCELED);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    uploadVideoFile();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                (RESULT_CANCELED);
                }
            });
        }

    };
```

On the

```
facebookClient.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, new Facebook.DialogListener()
```

it tells me that 
`The method authorize(Activity, String[], Facebook.DialogListener) in the type Facebook is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, String[], new Facebook.DialogListener(){}).`

I am stuck and confused on this, please any help will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

that's because your `this` that is being passed to the authorize() method is the instance of the Activity. try replacing it with the name of your onClickListener, which should be `myButtonOnClickListener`

Comment: It's the other way around. He should put ActivityName.this there.